# React: Not able to render values in an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-component, react-functional-component

I have a component defined as shown below. `creativeList` contains values that I'm interested in displaying. It contains the following:

```
creativeList = [{keyID: "AC072", cost: 1461, people: 520, cpp: "2.81"}, 
{keyID: "AC098", cost: 1600, people: 470, cpp: "3.4"}]
```

I would like to be able to display the `keyID` by returning it in my component. I am able to get the value by logging to the console, however, I'm not able to return it. Can someone help me out?

```
function DisplayList(props) {
    const creativeList = props.creativeList

    function ret(){
        creativeList.forEach(function(item){
            const i = item[0]

            console.log(i.keyID)

            return (
                <li>{i.keyID}</li>
            );
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <li>List:</li>
            {ret()}
        </div>
    );
}

export default DisplayList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add a return statement just before forEach statement and replace forEach by map

map returns an array of the elements returned by its callback parameter, unlike forEach.

forEach returns undefined, that's why your list is not getting print.

```
function ret(){
        return creativeList.map(function(item){

            console.log(item.keyID)

            return (
                <li>{item.keyID}</li>
            );
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This. You missed to return a component and ofcourse you should use map instead of foreach

```
import React from "react";

function DisplayList(props) {
  const creativeList = props.creativeList;


  function ret() {
    return creativeList.map(function(item) {
      const i = item;

      console.log(i.keyID);

      return <li>{i.keyID}</li>;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <li>List:</li>
      {ret()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default DisplayList;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop forEach, if you want to do return, forEach returns undefined, use map instead.
working example: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-williamson-z4b66)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify using the `map`. Also add the `key` attribute to each element in list.

```
function DisplayList(props) {
  const { creativeList = [] } = props.creativeList;
  return (
    <div>
      <div>List:</div>
      {creativeList.map(({ keyID }) => (
        <li key={keyID}>{keyID}</li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
export default DisplayList;
```